# Automating Google Chrome extension packaging

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, packaging

I'm trying to automate packaging of the Chrome extension on Windows and according to the documentation, it is this command:

```
[path]\chrome.exe --pack-extension=c:\myext --pack-extension-key=c:\myext.pem --no-message-box
```

However this command results in a new browser window and no action is performed. I tried other switches like --version or --help but it seems that Chrome is ignoring all of this. Do others have the same issue? What am I doing wrong? I also tried various quoting and with no other browser window open but I haven't been able to make this work.

**Update:** I'm happy to learn that the new Chrome 8 has fixed this issue.

Comment: what version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: You can try one of the scripts to pack an extension at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/crx.html#scripts

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome (7.0.517.44). @Na7coldwater thanks! the script worked on Ubuntu but I need to do this on a Windows machine and the script produces as error in Cygwin. I think this is a workable solution. If you have this as an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: You can also check programmatic ways to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59009114/520567

Answer (score 5):

The answer is present in one of the comments. I am reposting the answer verbatim here:

> You can try one of the scripts to pack
>   an extension at
>   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx#scripts
>   – by [Na7coldwater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364136/na7coldwater)

Comment: The docs changed and the link broke. Here it is in the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20180114090616/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to close all chrome windows before the command line `pack extension` command will work.

I raised this bug with the chrome team some time ago (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=22901) but it's not quite fixed yet. This can be somewhat frustrating because (as michaelhermannweber pointed out) "Since we're fans of Chrome, obviously Chrome is already open!"

I even tried to use a separate instance of the chrome executable to build the extension, but alas no luck on that front either :(
For now, AFAICT you have to do it manually via the pack extension button on the chrome://extensions page.

You might manage to build a script that closes all open chrome windows, builds the extension, and then re-opens chrome. But I doubt that it would be worth it given the number of tab users like to keep open.

Comment: I had already tried with all the Chrome windows closed but the command just opens the Chrome back up. Does the packing work for you from the command line? I can't get any of the other switches to work either, e.g., --version