# Generating Chrome Packaged App .crx header with Java

Tags: google-app-engine, rsa, x509, google-chrome-app

I"m trying to build the header in Java with no luck.
(here is the spec: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx)
Any ideas?

```java
protected void geneateCrxHeader (OutputStream ins,byte[] zipArchive) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException{


    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");      
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
    keyGen.initialize(1024, random);        

    KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    byte[] key = pair.getPublic().getEncoded();     

    Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    instance.initSign(pair.getPrivate());
    instance.update(zipArchive);                        
    byte[] hash = instance.sign();              
 byte[] magic = {0x43,0x72,0x32,0x34,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x0E,0x0B,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00};

    ins.write(magic);
    ins.write(key);
    ins.write(hash);
}
```

and I get CRX_EXCESSIVELY_LARGE_KEY_OR_SIGNATURE..
I must be using wrong keygen.

in the docs they do say : 
**"..the contents of the author's RSA public key, formatted as an X509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo block. .."
i wonder if that is what i'm not doing correctly...**

p.s Java crypto is a new frontier for me , so pls don't laugh if I did something totally dumb.

Comment: Well your public key length and signature length seem to be hard-coded. Where did you get the bytes `0x00,0x01,0x0E,0x0B` that you're using for your public key length?

Comment: my attempt to represent 491 bytes length. But I like the solution below MUCH better . didn't know you could do "headerBuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);"     now I know :) def. learned something today.   I'll give it a try in a real piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that I whipped up and didn't test that illustrates producing just the header. I based this solely on reading the spec.

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;

    public static byte[] generateCrxHeader(byte[] extensionContents) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");      
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        keyGen.initialize(1024, random);        

        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

        Signature sigInstance = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        sigInstance.initSign(pair.getPrivate());
        sigInstance.update(extensionContents);
        byte [] signature = sigInstance.sign();
        byte [] subjectPublicKeyInfo = pair.getPublic().getEncoded();
        final int headerLength = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + subjectPublicKeyInfo.length + signature.length;
        ByteBuffer headerBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(headerLength);
        headerBuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        headerBuf.put(new byte[]{0x43,0x72,0x32,0x34}); // Magic number
        headerBuf.putInt(2); // Version
        headerBuf.putInt(subjectPublicKeyInfo.length); // public key length
        headerBuf.putInt(signature.length); // signature length
        headerBuf.put(subjectPublicKeyInfo);
        headerBuf.put(signature);
        final byte [] header = headerBuf.array();
        return header;
    }
```

Comment: That's IT !!!!!!!   thank you . Sllopy byte[] work on my part. using ByteBuffer was the key here.  And I was convinced i was using wrong crypto algorithm.