# Is there a node package to empackage chrome extension?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently writing an extension generator for Chrome Browser using NodeJS ; I want it as portable as possible and try to avoid using command line.

If someone is interested, there is the command for windows :

```
   chrome.exe --pack-extension=c:\myext --pack-extension-key=c:\myext.pem
```

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks to you.

Comment: A few seconds of googling shows there are [some utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196615/how-to-create-chrome-crx-file-programmatically-preferably-in-java) so hopefully you can find what you look for.

Comment: Asking initially for a node package who allows it, but np, i'll surely check the py script. Ty.

Comment: Well, StackOverflow deems software searching off-topic but if you find a base for your solution and create your own extension or an npm package, it might make sense to add an answer that links it and describes some useful info (e.g. why it's better than the official approach, in which cases, etc.) so that it's not just a link.

Comment: Okey, thanks for your time ! :D

Answer (score 0):

This is the package I was looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/crx ! 
No need to create one (: